# ¿Como detecto si un objeto esta conectado a la fila mas alta de una cuadricula hexagonal?

Tags: c#, unity, grid

Estoy tratando de hacer un bubble shooter, ya tengo todo hecho menos una cosa, y es que cuando eliminas todas las bolas al rededor de un grupo, se quedan flotando, y me gustaria que tambien se destruyeran

asi es como creo y guardo los elementos de mi cuadricula

```csharp
 public static Dictionary<Vector2Int, GameObject> ArrayBalls = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, GameObject>();

for (var x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                float xpos = (x + y * 0.5f - y / 2);

                modifiedSpacing = Spacing;
                ArrayBalls.Add(new Vector2Int(x, y), Instantiate(BallPrefab, new Vector3(xpos * modifiedSpacing, y * modifiedSpacing, 0), transform.rotation, GridContainer.transform));
                ArrayBalls.TryGetValue(new Vector2Int(x, y), out var gridObject);
            }
        }
```

aqui hay una imagen para que se entienda mejor lo que me sucede
[image: Ejemplo de lo que pasa]

algunos me han dicho que ultilize flood fill para detectarlos pero cuando trate de hacerlo fracase, asi que me gustaria utilizar otro metodo o saber como ultilizar ese